# Getting post values of dynamically generated content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form generator essentially, what I want to do is take the forms list of questions, dynamically generate them on the page, then retrieve the answers.  Generating the questions is easy, but how do I retrieve those answers?  I don't see how I can strongly type the view, but is there a way to manually grab the post values if I know the name of the input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, access the form values directly:

```
var value = Request.Form["inputNameHere"];
```

Comment: That, or have action method with parameter of type `FormCollection`.